# Using threads in Java to process array elements

Tags: java, multithreading

Give an list of integers ( positive and negative ) stored in an array. How do I check if the numbers are positive, negative or zero concurrently.

I have thought of some possible ways of solving this:

- having three different methods that will be called form three different threads using `wait` and `notify`. ( works to some extent )
- having a single `synchronized` method and three different threads accessing it with a global counter. The threads communicate with each other. ( works to some extent )
- Giving the array in slices to threads. For example Thread 1 will work on half of the elements and Thread 2 on the other half. ( not implemented yet, not sure if this approach fits the definition of concurrent correctly ).

Please keep in mind that this was given as a College Assignment.

If someone would give some insights or thoughts on ways of solving this, would be very helpful.

Edit:

This was the exact question given. I tried to simplify it a little and approach it.

**Write a Java program which first generates a set of random numbers and then determines negative, positive even, positive odd numbers concurrently.**

Comment: 3rd one is the best approach.

Comment: @Amongalen I was thinking that too. But does it fits the definition of "concurrently" ?

Comment: Are you permitted to use either `ConcurrentQueue` or `Executor`?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- No, that it the problem

Comment: If you want to get extra fancy with approach 3, try implementing this using a `ForkJoinPool` which is essentially specifically designed for this. I find it very unintuitive to code though, so I suggest only trying it after finishing the actual assignment.

Answer (score 0):

To explain it simply:

1. This approach is usually good when threads do different work that is dependent on each other. For example, one thread produces some data and the other consumes them.
2. `synchronized` is used to ensure only one thread at a time can perform a certain method. Usually used to access some data that have to be shared. For example, multiple threads do their work but then need to update some counter or something. That update would have to be synchronized.
3. By doing this you ensure each thread has its own data to work on it and don't have to communicate with other threads. Because of that more processing time is spent doing actual work and less on communication which can't be concurrent.

In your task, you probably should use 3rd and 2nd methods. First, you slice your data, process it, and then in a synchronized method add the final result to some counter (unless done in a totally separate thread after everything is done).

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this approach a try.

Answer (score 0):

### Using parallelStream

Though this is not technically using explicit threads, it uses multiple threads under the hood. It is concurrent. Add/remove counters and peek logic as per your requirements.

Give it a try if you like

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ConcurrentCounter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int n = 100;
        final int half = n / 2;
        final Random random = new Random();

        // generate random numbers (use IntStream rather than Random.int(n) to control range to test
        // other generating zero will be difficult. else explicitly add zeros
        List<Integer> numbers = IntStream.range(0, n)
            .map(i -> random.nextInt(n) - half).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(numbers);

        // two counters for -ve, +ve (zero can be counted as total - (-ve + +ve)
        AtomicInteger positive = new AtomicInteger(0);
        AtomicInteger negative = new AtomicInteger(0);

        // multithreaded using ForkJoin Pool - beware this can be less performant
        numbers.parallelStream().peek(i -> {
            if (i < 0) {
                negative.incrementAndGet();
            } else if (i > 0) {
                positive.incrementAndGet();
            }
        }).count(); // do not remove this dummy count(), otherwise this will not be executed as this statement will be come no-op

        int zero = n - (positive.get() + negative.get());

        System.out.println("Negative: " + negative.get() + ", Zero: " + zero + ", Positive: " + positive.get());
    }
}
```